# __restrict pointer aliasing with only one pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

Is there any advantage to specifying the MSVC/GCC non-standard  `__restrict` qualifier on a function pointer parameter if it is the only pointer parameter? For example,

```
int longCalculation(int a, int* __restrict b)
```

My guess is it should allow better optimization since it implies `b` does not point to `a`, but all examples I've seen `__restrict` two pointers to indicate no aliasing between them.

Comment: `b` cannot point to `a` anyway! It's just impossible. Try it.

Comment: Good point, since `a` is passed by value. Didn't think of that.

Comment: `restrict` is actually part of the C99 standard, so this is not exactly non-standard (though I don't think any C++ spec has adopted it yet.)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: it's actually non-standard! The restrict-keyword is not present in any C++ standard (including the recent C++11).

Comment: Ah, I thought C++11 might have adopted it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `b` can't point to `a` anyways, so there is no aliasing potential there anyways. So if the function is pure in the sense that it works only on its parameters there shouldn't be any real benefits.

However if the function uses *global variables* internally then `__restrict` might offer benefits once again, since it makes clear that `b` doesn't point to any of those global variables.

An interesting case might be the situation where you allocate and deallocate memory inside the function. The compiler could theoretically be sure that `b` doesn't point to that memory, however whether or not it realizes that I'm not sure and might depend how the allocation is called.

Personally however I prefer to keep `__restrict` out of the signature and do something like this

```
int longCalculation(int a, int* b){ 
   assert(...);//ensure that b doesn't point to anything used
   int* __restrict bx = b;
   ...
}
```

IMO this has the following advantages:

- The function signature doesn't expose the non standard `__restrict` used
- The ability to ensure that the variables actually conform to `__restrict` using  `assert`, since passing aliasing pointers to a function expecting them to be nonaliasing can lead to hard to track down bugs.

Comment: Your code aliases `bx` and `b` and is the exact situation `restrict` guarantees cannot ever happen.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: `restrict`guarantees nothing. What it is is a promise to the compiler not to access the *data pointed to by the restricted pointer* through any other means (pointers) during the lifetime of that pointer.  So setting `bx` to point at `b` is not a problem as long as `b` isn't derefferenced inside the function (which should be fairly obvious as a bad idea).